# Code still executing after returning res.send

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a function that will return a response **`res.send()`** but after that function is called, the following line of code is till executed.

```
const db = require('../models');

exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    checkAuthorization(req, res, 'Customer');

    db.User.findAll({ include: ['created', 'restaurant'] })
        .then((data) => {
            res.send({
                error: false,
                data: data,
                message: ['Retrieved successfully.'],
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send({
                error: true,
                data: [],
                message: err.errors.map((e) => e.message),
            });
        });
};
```

---

Here is the `checkAuthorization` function

```
const checkAuthorization = (req, res, user_type) => {
    // Check if user_type param is null
    if (user_type == null) return res.status(500).send('`user_type` parameter is required');

    // Check if user_type param has valid value
    const validuser_type = user_type === 'Customer' || user_type === 'Resto_Admin' || user_type === 'Admin';

    // Validate user_type parameter
    if (!validuser_type) return res.status(500).send('The value for `user_type` parameter is invalid');

    // Check if user is not authorized
    if (!(req.user != null && req.user.user_type === user_type))
        return res.status(401).send('Oops! You are unauthorized to view your request');
};
```

---

Here is the error I get.

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: *but after that function is called, the following line of code is till executed* yes, it is ... `res.send` doesn't "terminate" a function .. only `return` does that

Comment: `res.send()` doesn’t end callback method execution, and I’m not aware of any Express documentation that would  substantiate a claim to the contrary, so I’m unsure how you reached this conclusion. There are an innumerable number of use cases in which you would need to perform additional processing after a response is sent, are there not?

Comment: @Bravo I assume it will end `exports.findAll` function because I use `return` keyword on `checkAuthorization` function that is called before the next lines of codes. It works when I didn't use `checkAuthorization` function but I need that function to reuse it.

Comment: @PaulTulod: *"because I use return keyword on checkAuthorization function"* - Which ends the execution of that function and passes control back to the calling code.  But returning from a function has never also caused all calling functions up the stack to also return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Returning from a function" and "returning a response to the user from a web server" are two very different things.  The `checkAuthorization` function is sending a response, but then doesn't indicate to the calling function that it did that.  So the calling function also tries to send a response.

Don't "return" the call to `res.status` from `checkAuthorization`.  If it needs to send a response, it can do so but should also return from the function some indication that it did this.  Something as simple as a boolean value can work.  For example:

```
const checkAuthorization = (req, res, user_type) => {
  // Check if user_type param is null
  if (user_type == null) {
    res.status(500).send('`user_type` parameter is required');
    return false;
  }
  // and so on for the other responses...

  // then, if no condition produced an HTTP response...
  return true;
}
```

And then when invoking that function:

```
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
  if (!checkAuthorization(req, res, 'Customer')) {
    // the function internally sent a response, stop processing
    return;
  }

  db.User.findAll({ include: ['created', 'restaurant'] })
  //...
};
```

---

As an aside... This overall logic structure can get confusing fast.  What you probably want to do is move your `checkAuthorization` logic into [its own middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) that would be invoked on every request, before the request even reaches the `findAll` logic in this case.

In the middleware pipeline you can use `res` to send a response to the user and then end processing, or invoke `next` to continue processing.